# Docker: COPY failed to find Gemfile: no such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm currently working on setting up a Rails boilerplate via docker. When I try to run `docker build .` I get the following error:

```
Step 5/8 : COPY Gemfile /app/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder090950451/Gemfile: no such file or directory
```

I'm following the directions in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) but I still have not been able to build the image.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the existing Gemfile
COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock

# Install Gems
RUN bundle install
COPY . /app
```

I also have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres # To Edit - Default is postgresql.
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I generated the Rails application by running `docker-compose run web rails new app --force --database=postgresql` which does generates the rails application with its Gemfile as shown in the image below.[image]

However after generating the rails application and running `docker-compose build` I get the following error:

```
db uses an image, skipping
Building web
Step 1/7 : FROM ruby:2.5
 ---> 55fb4a37704e
Step 2/7 : RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
 ---> Using cache
 ---> afb6f347904c
Step 3/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1fdbd260685d
Step 4/7 : COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder885442968/Gemfile: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Is your Dockerfile in your app directory? Can't see properly in the VSCode dir structure.

Comment: @johnharris85 its out the app directory

Comment: So that's the problem, the build context is by default where your Dockerfile is, and Gemfile doesn't exist in there. I went to the docs you're following, and they're in the same dir there.

Comment: but how could it be if the sub folder `app` doesn't have a Gemfile? In the `app` folder is where `controllers`, `helpers` and `models` live.

Comment: you were right it worked. I  dont get how

Comment: @johnharris85 what if I want to have a folder `app` that has the rails application and to have the other files live outside the Rails application. How would the path change to?

Comment: You can just change the line to `COPY ./app/Gemfile /app/Gemfile`

Comment: @johnharris85 that didn't work it gave me error: `ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 18`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174510/discussion-between-johnharris85-and-steven-aguilar).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is I named the container directory and the app directory the same `app` which caused the issues of not finding the Gemfile.

I updated the `Dockerfile` to:

```
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

WORKDIR /webapp

COPY ./app/Gemfile /webapp/Gemfile
COPY ./app/Gemfile.lock /webapp/Gemfile.lock

RUN cd /webapp && bundle install
ADD . /webapp
```

and in the docker-compose.yml I changed the `volumes` to:

```
volumes:
      - .:/webapp
```

This is only if you want to have the Rails application stand alone and for the `Docker` files to live outside the the rails application.

Comment: It's strange but i fully copied your Dockerfile and still got error:
```Step 4/7 : COPY ./app/Gemfile /webapp/Gemfile
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder085947770/app/Gemfile: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an earlier volume named `bundle` which was used by a different docker image.

So whenever I ran this other docker image, which had a different workdir and also required a `bundle` volume, it threw a similar error message as above.

To fix it, I just had to prune older volumes, which included the old `bundle` volume, then reran the build

```
docker volume prune

docker build .
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove ./dir/

```
COPY ./Gemfile /webapp/Gemfile 
COPY ./Gemfile.lock /webapp/Gemfile.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that if you have the line:
***WORKDIR /app*** you are already in the polder app. So when you COPY something into docker container you do not need to write ./app or /app because . means that this is an app already. And if you write such a thing it will be copied to the new **app** dir inside your WORKDIR and the path will be **/app/app**.
In your case the Dockerfile should look like:

```
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the existing Gemfile
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock .

# Install Gems
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue anyway when working on a **Rails** application in **Ubuntu** 18.04.

I was getting this error:

> ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder805666212/Gemfile: no such file or directory

The issue was that I had multiple `docker-compose.yml` files, and I was making file changes to the wrong one which was inside a directory and not the root directory.

All I had to do was to delete that `docker-compose.yml` and make the file changes on the `docker-compose.yml` in the root directory.

Then, I ran the command below for the `docker-compose.yml` file in the root directory:

```
docker-compose build
```

and everything worked fine again.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**